# Dependency 'org.unitils:unitils-core:3.4' not found

Tags: java

while trying to add unitils dependency in my pom.xml getting error as *"Dependency 'org.unitils:unitils-core:3.4' not found "*

[image]
Adding unitils dependency to use below function:

```
public static String compareObjects(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        String report = null;
        try {
            Difference difference = ReflectionComparatorFactory
                    .createRefectionComparator(new ReflectionComparatorMode[]{ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER,
                            ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS})
                    .getDifference(obj1, obj2);
            System.out.println("Difference object " + ObjectMapperHelper.objectToString(difference));
            if (difference != null) {
                DefaultDifferenceReport diffReport = new DefaultDifferenceReport();
                report = diffReport.createReport(difference);
            }
            return difference != null ? report : null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return report;
    }
```

POM file dependences as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

P.S Github repo: https://github.com/Pulkit773/RestAssured/tree/main

Comment: is it maybe a scope problem? I mean, you do you need this dependency during test execution?
If not, try removing that `<scope>test</scope>` line

Comment: Copying your POM and code verbatim into a project does not yield the error and I can run it without issue. Your problem is not reproducible with the information you have given.

Comment: @pochopsp removing scope is not helping.

Comment: @possum I added the github repo path. can you please try with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.4 is accessible on [maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/unitils/unitils-core/3.4/) and downloadable

So you have probably a problem with your maven/IDE configuration.

Tested on Eclipse2023 with maven plugin (embedded maven), downloaded jar without any error.

Please provide maven settings.

EDIT: OP provided the project.

**Change needed in pom.xml**

Old library from 2006. Probably one of the first version of concurrent lib that seems to be embedded in jdk since a very long time.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Invalid location for some dependencies:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
                        <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Your dependencies should be under project ==> dependencies, not project ==> build ==> plugin ==> dependencies. I do not know exactly what is the purpose of declaring dependencies under build, but it is what prevents you to use test scope.

Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B

I do not know exactly why maven can't find this jar but it is irrelevant. Hibernate need this library by

Jackson core already imported by Jackson bind

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Removed.

A lot of other problems or modifications needeed. But here is a functionnal pom that will able you to continue your work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestAssuredFramework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.21.1</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Add the following options to your maven-surefire-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
            <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I added the github repo path. can you please try with the same

Comment: Multiple problem in your pom, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks so much to helping out for unitils